# How to pass ${keyWord} to config.url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this line of code:

```
axios.get(`https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=sv&text=${keyWord}`).then(
```

not doing its job, but it carries my input with `${keyWord}`. How do I put `${keyWord}` into this line of code

```
url: 'https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=sv&text=ett',
```

so that when I input searching content, my `config.url` changes accordingly.

```
search =()=>{
    
    const {keyWordElement:{value:keyWord}} = this
    PubSub.publish('msg',{isFirst:false, isLoading:true}

    const axios = require('axios');

    const config = {
      
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=sv&text=ett',
      headers: { 
        'Authorization': 'Basic xxxx'
      }
    };

    axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data)); 
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });

    axios.get(`https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=sv&text=${keyWord}`).then(
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to dynamically change your URL.
`url: 'https://dictapi.lexicala.com/search?source=global&language=sv&text=ett'+ keyWord`

Comment: Why people devote my question? your solution works, thank you